# Hide HTML From Client Side

Tags: javascript, html, dom, server-side, client-side

I have scrapped a listing website (for example ebay though its not ebay) and if the listing is duplicate in my database which i am checking through some logic, i have shown some information from my database alongwith original listing on the website by injecting some html on the run time.

Now, i know the website owner whose website i have scrapped (ebay in this example) can retrieve modified html of the client side of all the sessions using javascript. How do i secure my portion of html or complete modified html in such a case so that the website owner is not able to access my html which i am accessing on the server side.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and looking forward to the solution.

Comment: I believe you are asking if you can hide the HTML that built the page from a user that is already on your page correct?

Comment: For example , i am again using the ebay listing site and now i am seeing my injected html as well. I want this whole html to be protected or my injected html to be protected though my injected html is part of the whole html page now so that ebay listing site cannot access on the server side.

Comment: How are you injecting into someone else's site in the first place?

Comment: i am just injecting some html on the run time itself on the final rendered html page of this listing website after doing some processing via chrome extension. so this html is just visible to me. and is part of my session.

Comment: I don't believe there is a away to do what to do.  HTML has to be visible to the browser which by default has to visible to the user, if they are on that page.  Now there is back end code, server side, which the browser does not see and the client end user does not have access to as it is not render onto the page.  As far as HTML, JavaScript, and CSS you can change the settings on your browser window to what you want.  If the site's creator is not careful this is one way you can get hacked.

Comment: So having scraped someone else's html you are now looking for ways to avoid someone scraping your html?

Comment: @lucas i am just trying to protect myself from site owner which is ebay in this example so that they does not know that we have scrapped their website and how we are comparing the listings & what analytics we are doing after scrapping. I didnt get any relevant answers till now. Does everyone here know that siteowner can access html of their webpage via javascript at various time intervals & then send that to server side for analysis. i am trying to stop this if the site owner is as intelligent as me & can think of such a functionality for their website to analyze what their visitors are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use iFrame-s, site owner can only access the iframes from the same domain as the page.

Comment: Let me try your solution tomorrow and will let you know whether it worked though i feel i am not protecting others from accessing. i just want website owner to not retrieve my updated client side html through server side code deployed by him.

Comment: obviously site owner is the owner of the domain so they can access iframes. i have injected html into their website listings only.